# Alternative to Firebase for Huge Data sets

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Our app has found great success recently.  Part of the app consists of a huge list of products.  Products that we have stored on Firebase’s Realtime Database.  However our Data set for the list we populate has now exceeded 5,000+ objects.  Which of course has put great strain on our Realtime Database, causing our loading time of these products to push 1 minute + on the initial load and 18 secs+ after caching using Firebase’s persistent data cache.

I’ve been reading other questions pertaining to huge data sets and utilizing Firebase and the short answer is “don’t do it”.

However, what wasn’t addressed, and the “pickle” we’re in is what “can” we do?  Is there somewhere else where we can host our data that will query our data exponentially faster?

Because of our use-case, pagination isn’t an option.  The JSON is around 12MB.   Any advice or “We ran into the same roadblock and this is what we did” would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

How we query for data:

```
   [_reference
 observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
 withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
     self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
     self.postCountNew = 0;
     for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
         [_dataArray addObject:snapshot.value];
         int timeInterval =
         [now timeIntervalSinceDate:[_dateFormatter dateFromString:snapshot.value[@"Date"]]];
         if (timeInterval < 86400 && timeInterval >= 0 && timeInterval != 0) {
             _postCountNew++;
         }
     }
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     completionBlock (YES);
 }];
```

Comment: How big is each node? Are you downloading all of them? Or do you query for only the relevant nodes? Do you have an index defined on the fields you query?

Comment: To be clear: having 5000 child nodes is not a number to worry about. But if each node is 100K and you're trying to load all 5000 nodes to each client, then... yes... that will take time, and probably use more memory than the device has available.

Comment: The nodes vary depending on the product, but lets say one node is a pair of shoes, that branches to 9 nodes: likes, dislikes, title, description, productId, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but there are way too many unknowns here to answer. Can you turn this into a concrete question that we might be able to answer without knowing your exact project. Typically this goes best if you isolate (part of) the problem, e.g. into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
This topic might be more suited for the firebase-talk mailing list, although to be honest: there too they'll want to know what specific answer you're looking for.

Comment: We query using observeSingleEvent for value and then have data sync turned on.

Comment: I'll edit the question

Comment: That sounds like a combination that is non-ideal. Are you trying to load all data at app start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164374/discussion-between-joshua-hart-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Comment: If `_reference` points to 12MB of data and you're re-downloading that every time the app starts, it's going to take a while. If your download speed is 250KB/s, you're looking at 48 seconds of speed just to download the raw bytes. Adding protocol overhead and time to decode the data in the client, and 1 minute sounds like pretty optimal. The solution in cases such as this is to download less data. It's unlikely you're going to show 12MB of data in a single screen on a mobile device. So focus on downloading precisely the data that you need to show on the initial screen.